# Azure Microsoft Graph Count Parameter

Tags: typescript, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to send a request via one of my tests to the graph api URI /users, I'm attempting to get a countOnly response from the request but can't seem to find the key they specify in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=http#code-try-36).

Here is my test, which includes a wrapper to create the apiInstance which works fine.

```
it('should return a count of users', async () => {
    const initialResponse = await apiInstance.get(`/users?$count=true`);
    console.log(initialResponse);
  });
```

This is just a vite-test to attempt to figure out how to use the count parameter.

The response I get from this is [image: test response]

This does not seem to include the return value they specify in the docs for getting a response, that return value being

```
@odata.count
```

If you're wondering, that

```
 apiInstance.get
```

portion just uses the default URL to hit the api, that being

```
https://graph.microsoft.com
```

My question is basically, what am I doing wrong here? I'm passing the same URL they specify in the docs to get a count response but can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird behavior of the `/users` endpoint

You need to add `ConsistencyLevel` header with the value `eventual`. Then the response will contain `@odata.count`.

Not sure what is `apiInstance`, but something like this

```
it('should return a count of users', async () => {
    const initialResponse = await apiInstance.get(`/users?$count=true`, 'ConsistencyLevel: eventual');
    console.log(initialResponse);
  });
```